# MySQL remote access from windows cmd prompt

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, command-line, remote-access

I am new to MySQL.
There is an environment where mysql is installed and DB set up in an Linux server.
Is it possible to access the db using windows command prompt?
What would be the best way to access the db remotely from windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the -h option

```
mysql -u<user> -p -h <dbhost>
```

for example:

```
mysql -uroot -p -h myql.servername.com
```

Your user needs remote permissions at your host.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a new user , use some gui tool to control mysql like https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/wiki/Downloads . It will be easier for you.